# Ember.js handlebars if, else statement

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using Ember.js with handlebars templates, I've tried a number of ways to get handlebars #if else working for me but it always returns both the contents of if and else.. Here's the code I'm currently using.

App.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  selectedView: "Home",
  IsHome: function() {
    this.get('selectedView') === 'Home'
}.property('selectedView')

});
```

index.html head contains:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home-view">
      Hello, This is the home view.
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="edit-account">
      Hello, This is the account edit view.
</script>
```

and in the body:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#if App.IsHome}}
   {{view HomeView}}
{{else}}
  {{view editAccountView}}
{{/if}}
</script>
```

This ends up showing both views in the body of the page. Any advice is appreciated,

thanks
Steve

Comment: I forgot to add the view declarations in App.js:

var homeView = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'home-view',
}).appendTo('#right');

var editAccountView = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'edit-account',
}).appendTo(#right);

Comment: Take look at ember routing and outlet helper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental reason for your problem is the Handlebars view helper ( {{view MyView}} ) expects a path parameter to an Ember “class”, not an instance of a class. To create a view class use the `extend` method of `Ember.View`. The Handlebars view helper will instantiate your view class and append it to the document for you.

See this post for more information on the Ember object model and the differences between Ember’s `extend` and `create` methods:  http://ember-object-model.notlong.com.

Here is your example with a few changes made to correct the points I made above. http://jsfiddle.net/ethan_selzer/kcjzw/217/

Regards,

Ethan

Comment: Thanks for the response guys! Ok using Ethan's suggestion I can see it works in IE/FF but for some odd reason the output is empty in chrome. Anyway I've still been having issues, I think I'm missing something simple.. any ideas? This example only returns the else statement but looks to me to mimic Ethan's suggestion.. jsfiddle.net/sbignell/tjQ9s

Comment: Actually i've just fixed it.. i didnt have the isHome function quite right, thanks alot Ethan your solution works and I'll take a look at the documentation too.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you got it working. In addition to the documentation at [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com), the [github wiki](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki/Links) has a links page with some helpful articles and examples.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are appending both views (`homeView` and `editAccountView`) manually with `appendTo`.

Also, avoid defining views within the App `create()` function. Therefore, create your App:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    App.MainView.create().append();
  }
});
```

where `App.MainView` is your top-level view defined by:

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'main-view',

  selectedView: "Home",
  isHome: function() {
    this.get('selectedView') === 'Home'
  },

  homeView: Ember.View.extend({ 
    templateName: 'home-view'
  }),

  editAccountView: Ember.View.extend({ 
    templateName: 'edit-account'
  })
});
```

with the handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main-view">
  {{#if view.isHome}}
     {{view view.homeView}}
  {{else}}
    {{view view.editAccountView}}
  {{/if}}
</script>
```